# Generate multipe Apache Echarts after another gives initialize problem

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have created a function which generates echarts based on the selection in a dropdown.

```
switch(graphtype) {
        case "type1": 
            someNameECharts.createChartLineCat({graphData: data, 
                bindTo: "ResultsGraphBatch",
                width: 1000,
                height: 500})                                                        
            break;
        case "type2":
           // myChart.clear();
           // $("#ResultsGraphBatch").empty();
            someNameECharts.createChartLineCat({graphData: data, 
                bindTo: "ResultsGraphBatch",
                width: 1000,
                height: 500})                    
            break;
        etc.
```

someNameECharts.createChartLineCat refers to a function in a seperate .js file which generates the chart.

This works fine. By default "type1" is generated as expected. When I select "type2" I get this "There is a chart instance already initialized on the dom" Error.

I tried to solve it with a myChart.clear() option but "myChart" is not recognised. Emty the "Div" totally "removes" the div.

This is the function to generate the chart in my seperate .js file:

```
 let myChart
 someNameECharts.createChartLineCat = function(config) {

/// I removed some additional code to keep this short ////
if(myChart){
   myChart.clear();
 }
myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(config.bindTo), null, {width: config.width, height: config.height});
let option = {
    title: {
      text: config.title
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            dataZoom: {},
            saveAsImage: {},
            magicType: {
            type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack']
            }
        }
    },
    color: colorSchema,
    dataset: [
        {
            dimensions: [{name: keyNames[0], type:'ordinal'}, {name: keyNames[1]}, {name: keyNames[2]}],
            source: config.graphData,                
        },              
    ],
    tooltip: {},
    grid: {
      width: '70%',
      left: '3%',
      right: '4%',
      bottom: '3%',
      containLabel: true
    },
    legend: {
        orient: 'vertical',
        right: 10,
        top: 'center',
        },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
    },
    series: seriesSettings
};

outputDataset.forEach(function(ds) {
  option.dataset.push(ds);
});
    
myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

Comment: _"I tried to solve it with a myChart.clear() option but "myChart" is not recognised."_ - it is a variable local to your `createChartLineCat` method - so of course you don't have access to it, in a _second_ separate call to that method. Store it somewhere outside of the function.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I changes my .js file in the example above.    

if(myChart){
    myChart.clear();
  }

Comment: I solved it in vue 3, implementing a different id for each graph